# Is pressure frame-dependent?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, pressure, fluid-statics

Suppose Ryan presses the liquid in flask with piston inside a accelerating lift with acceleration $t$.
He presses it with force $F$ on area $A$ assume mass of fluid be $M$.

So from lift frame forces on liquid are F and Mt.So net pressure should be (F+Mt)/A.

But from ground frame pressure will be F/A.

So is **PRESSURE** frame dependent?

Comment: How did you reach the expression you say is valid in an accelerated frame? It is wrong

Comment: The person from ground missed to consider the [pseudo force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force)

Comment: i might have messed up with frames pl correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but force is **frame independent.**
So pressure is frame independent.